# PDO get sql error code - must be of the type integer

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to get the error code from MYSQL via PDO as integer?

```
try{
    ...
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    throw new Fatal($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

`$e->getCode()` will return something like `HY000`

> Argument 2 passed to Fatal::__construct() must be of the type integer,
>   string given ...
>
> ... Fatal->__construct('SQLSTATE[HY000]...', 'HY000')

Comment: 1. That's just how PDOExceptions are. Not much to be done about it. 2. Why bother catching it if you're just going to re-throw a functionally identical Exception? 3. The third argument in an Exception's constructor is `$previous` where you can pass in the previous Exception for proper chaining.

Comment: Because I pipe all fatal errors throgh the same Error class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `$e->errorInfo`.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php says:

> *errorInfo*
>
> - Corresponds to PDO::errorInfo() or PDOStatement::errorInfo()

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php documents the fields returned by `errorInfo()`.

Example:

```
try {
        $stmt = $pdo->query("Bogus Query");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Caught exception!\n";
        var_dump($e->errorInfo);
}
```

Output:

```
Caught exception!
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "42000"
  [1]=>
  int(1064)
  [2]=>
  string(157) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
      your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Bogus Query' at line 1"
}
```

You can see that the `[1]` element is an integer.

Comment: will `[1]` return `2006` when the error is `mysql server gone away`?

Comment: Yes, that's the code documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/client-error-reference.html